# where the conversion from 24 bit to 16 bit happens in kernel when recording

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, audio, pcm, alsa

I am recording with the format of S16_LE. Even though I set the format on my dai as S24_LE it is getting recorded in 16 bit recording in Linux.

Can anyone help me with this?

How can I find where the conversation is happening?

I am using Linux kernel and testing on the raspberry, for checking the spdif of wolfson card.

For AIF2 I am setting S24_LE and I am giving S16_LE as the input of it.

I don't know where the data conversation happening.

Comment: What progran are you using? `arecord`?

Comment: yes, i am using arecord for recording

Comment: Add the `-v` option, and show the output.

Comment: i am getting the same as i gave but intenal codec is configured with 24 bit. When i gave 16 bit record, it is recording, dont know why.

Comment: Why are you keeping the `arecord` output a secret?

Comment: `Hardware PCM card 1 'snd_rpi_wsp' device 0 subdevice 0
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 24000
  period_size  : 6000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 6000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 24000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 6755399441055744000`

i got this output for arecord

Comment: Nobody actively converts anything; some component just ignores the lowest eight bits.